# Multiclass Classification with thousands of factor levels through R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I need to classify articles (which have text labels that I converted into factors) into different categories.
The difficulty is that there are 100 000 unique articles and 800 unique categories.

I was about to use a Random Forest algorithm but it is limited to 32 factor levels in R.

What is the best model/approach to do this kind of massive classification ?

Thank you a lot for you help in advance !

ML_Enthousiast

Comment: Just checking if anyone would have an idea :)

Comment: Did you get any suggestions? I'm interested in the same thing...